# How to find relationship between a categorical nominal variable and numerical variable?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, scatterplot

I am interested in finding the relationship between a nominal categorical variable and a numerical variable. We can't use scatter diagrams, or measurements of correlations for finding such relationships.

Comment: What kind of relationship do you hypothesize between them or want to test? i.e. do you see one variable as predictor and one as outcome/dependent, or is this just data exploration?

Comment: Not as outcome/dependent, more as if a certain categorical variable has any form of relationship to its numerical variable peer.

Comment: Even so, you could perhaps use regression with the numeric variable as dependent and the nominal variable as categorical predictor? As for visualization, maybe violin plots?

Comment: Are there any simpler ways to find out relationships without employing regression? For example to explore  if the body style of car (nominal) has any relationship with how efficient an EV runs (numerical).

Comment: Regression would give you that information, and in my opinion it's a relatively simple way. There are probably other ways too.

Comment: Of course just plotting numeric variable means for each level of the nominal variable would also help you forward without any formal analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what you are trying to achieve here. I will first note that the following statement is wrong:

> We can't use scatter diagrams, or measurements of correlations for finding such relationships.

I note below how you can use a scatter plot with this sort of relationship, and there are ways to measure associations between nominal and numeric data. For example, a [point biserial correlation](https://www.statology.org/correlation-between-continuous-categorical-variables/) can be easily employed with a binary categorical variable.

If your goal is simply to investigate the relationship between the two in an *exploratory* way, one can employ histograms, density plots, boxplots, boxenplots, violin plots, etc. which are grouped by category if you are just seeing "how much of something" exists in a group or how much it varies. [One can even use a scatterplot for that purpose](https://bookdown.org/pingapang9/linear_models_bookdown/chap-categorical.html) if you dummy code the categorical variable, then jitter the points to see how the data is distributed.

Now this will be different if you are trying to test some hypothesis or run some kind of confirmatory analysis. As Sointu mentioned in the comments, a simple regression would work for this, though it will depend on what you consider the dependent variable here. If the numeric variable is the dependent variable, then you just have to run a regression with a dummy-coded categorical variable as one of your predictors. If the categorical data is your dependent variable, that will depend on the nature of the categories For example, a simple binary grouping of "male" and "female" can be similarly dummy coded as $0$ or $1$ and then run as a logistic regression rather than a typical OLS regression.

For more complicated outcomes (more than one level of the categorical variable, ordering in the outcome, etc.), you may consider ordinal regression or multinomial regression.